# Is application/octet-stream a safe MIME type to accept when accepting CSV files?

Tags: php, file-upload, csv

I'm building a web form to take a CSV file to then import the contents into a contacts database. However, during development I've noticed when uploading a CSV file the MIME type available to me is `application/octet-stream`.

A quick web search on Google tells me that `application/octet-stream` is a generic MIME type for binary files, which could be anything from a `.csv` to a `.exe` file, which doesn't seem safe to me as then the only other piece of information I have to determine the file type is the original filename. And this can easily be changed by any one with basic computing knowledge.

How can I ensure that a CSV file uploaded via a web form in PHP is actually a CSV file with the above information?

Comment: Have you made any progress yet? Please let me know if I can help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is correct, `application/octet-stream` is a generic MIME type.

You could check whether the file has the CSV extension and use the function [fgetcsv()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to determine whether the content of the file is valid. This function will return NULL or boolean false if there are problems reading the file as CSV.

Comment: Thanks, Michiel. I was unsure how to really tell I was getting a CSV and uneasy on resting on file extension and filename alone, but knowing `fgetcsv()` returns false on error is good to know and I'll take that approach.

Answer (score 1):

to validate a file, you shouldn't depend on the mime-type as this can easily be manipulated. same thing for file-extension. it just takes 15 seconds to bypass this kind of "security checks".

the **only** safe way is to check the content of the file to see if it contains valid csv-data.

Answer (score 0):

When uploading files, you should never, **never** rely on MIME-types. They can be altered by the user.